# Which API is behind the privacy feature "Input Monitoring" in the Security system preferences of macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: macos, accessibility, keyboard-events

In macOS 10.15 Catalina there is a new section in the Security system preferences called **Input Monitoring**.

It says:

> Allow the apps below to monitor input from your keyboard even while using other apps.

I wonder which API is behind this to get apps into this this section.

I know `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions()`, which adds an app to the *Accessibility* section above *Input Monitoring*. Then I can use `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, handler: self.keyDown(event:))` to watch key presses from other apps. But what is *Input Monitoring* then good for?

It looks like adding an app to *Input Monitoring* manually doesn't allow you to use `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(...)`.

Apps like Steam have been put into that section after updating to Catalina, so there has to be something that tells the system to put them there...

[image]

Comment: Possibly a [`CGEventTap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_event_services).

Comment: Check out IOHIDRequestAccess and related functions (in <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDLib.h>), and the WWDC 2019 talk "Advances in macOS Security". Unfortunately I'm finding them buggy as hell though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@Nick Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220847/nick-moore) is right. This API is only available since 10.15.

There are two types of request for `IOHIDRequestAccess()`, and there is barely any doc about it :-( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/3181574-iohidrequestaccess?language=objc

```
if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
    // below requests "Input Monitoring"
    IOHIDRequestAccess(kIOHIDRequestTypeListenEvent)
    // below requests "Accessibility"
    IOHIDRequestAccess(kIOHIDRequestTypePostEvent)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a WWDC 2019 session on that with some more details: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/701

Comment: Just came across my own question: Adding the app to "Input Monitoring" is enough to [listen to events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454426-tapcreate), but if we also want to post your own events like key strokes, one have should add the app to "Accessibility".